# Parse xml fields only in specific tags

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse xml feed in flickr. 
API gives such answer

```
blah-blah-blah
qweqweqweq
<title>qfasf</title>

<entry>
<title>Hello</title>
blah-blah
</entry>
```

My code

```
while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (parser.getEventType()) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                if (parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    image.imgTitle = parser.nextText();
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, image.getImgTitle());
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {

                }
            default:
                break;
            }
            parser.next();
```

But it's parsing all titles in text. How to make it parse only Entries titles?
And ones more question how to parse Properties(href) in tag

```
 <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7297/8716931515_3e8d0826ff_b.jpg" />
```

Comment: lol @ blah-blah-qweqwe

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = db.parse(document);
NodeList name = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
System.out.println("Name: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
```

This way is cleaner:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.parse(new File("input.xml"));
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("title");
```

And you have your nodeList, to make whatever you want (take the text, ...)

Comment: oh, can u check it by real example of api answer?
http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=xml
Where u choose Entry tag?How it works :D

Comment: I can see a beautiful bath : D

Answer (score 0):

I suppose XPath is your friend here. You should probably look to dig more in to XPath tutorials on google.
For example one link you might want to see is [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)